# Where can I exchange Chilean Pesos in Bangkok, Thailand?

Tags: money, thailand, exchange, chile, bangkok

Well, [I've done it again.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/16568/82)  I forgot to change my currency before traveling, and now I'm stuck with a bunch of foreign currency that nobody seems to want!

This time, I'm in Bangkok, and I've got a whole bunch of Chilean Pesos.

I tried a bunch of currency exchanges at Suvarnabhumi Airport, as well as a few locations throughout Bangkok.  Nobody wants my Pesos!

Where can I exchange my Chilean Pesos in Bangkok?

At this point, I'm willing to trade them for any other currency — Thai Baht, US Dollars, Bitcoin...

Comment: Did you try to ask at the [Chilean Consulate in Thailand](http://chileabroad.gov.cl/tailandia/en/sobre-la-embajada/donde-estamos/)?

Comment: @uncovery Good suggestion.  I sent them an email; unfortunately, they don't change Pesos, and they did not offer me any suggestions, neither.  I'm gonna ping them back one more time with more specific questions, just to be sure.

Comment: You are pretty much out of luck, as South American and Latin American currencies are not traded much in SE Asia, even in Singapore.  You might try exploring the thaivisa.com forums, as lots of expats hang out there and maybe you might get lucky and find someone from the Americas or maybe traveling there willing to do a friendly trade.

Answer (score 1):

This is the biggest [money exchange hub](http://www.superrich1965.com/) in Bangkok which I don't see Chilean Pesos. However, I suggest you call them up and ask them.

Comment: Funnily enough; I actually visited their Silom branch earlier today and asked them about it. They do not buy Chilean Pesos.